# How to change the default filename for screenshots with the new gnome 42 screenshot tool?

Tags: linux, gnome, screenshot, gnome-42

I cannot figure out how to change the default filename for screenshots with the new **gnome 42** screenshot tool. Die Screenshots are saved in my screenshot folder, but the name is not in the format that I would like.

Currently the files are saved in this format:
`Screenshot from 2023-01-14 15-37-28.png`
However, I save most my documents in a format with a shorter date/time and also leading the filename with the date, e.g. `20230114-153728_screenshot.png`

I found some ways to do it with the old tool (`gnome-screenshot`):

- [askubuntu.com: How can I auto-generate a filename for gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984188/how-can-i-auto-generate-a-filename-for-gnome-screenshot)
- [askubuntu.com: How can i change the default name for the screenshots made by gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55204/how-can-i-change-the-default-name-for-the-screenshots-made-by-gnome-screenshot)
- [howtoforge.com: A comprehensive guide to taking screenshots in Linux using gnome-screenshot](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/taking-screenshots-in-linux-using-gnome-screenshot)

But I was not able to accomplish this with the new one. I couldn't even figure out how to start the interactive UI for the gnome 42 tool from the command line.

Comment: It seems to be an elementary screenshot tool with no menu.  I can press the Round button and that saves my selection to the Pictures folder.  From there I can rename the file to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using Autokey keyboard macro tool which uses Python 3+.

```
# [ win + w ] process gnome screenshot caption
# 2023-06-04 09:54 - AutoKey

clipboard.fill_clipboard("")
time.sleep(0.1)

paste_ = "<ctrl>+v"
time.sleep(0.1)

# example = "Screenshot from 2023-05-14 17-59-48" 
text_ = clipboard.get_selection()
time.sleep(0.1)

# replace unwanted chars in string 
text_ = text_.replace("-","") 
text_ = text_.replace(" ","_")
time.sleep(0.1)
# result = Screenshot_from_20230514_175948

# leftlen_ = 18 
# lefttext_ = "Screenshot_from_20"
lefttext_ = text_[:18] #left length
time.sleep(0.1)

# midlen_ = 6 
# midtext_ = "230514" year
# midtext_ = text_[::6:] #mid length
time.sleep(0.1)

# rightlen_ = 13
# righttext_ = "230514_175948" 
righttext_ = text_[-13:] #right length
time.sleep(0.1)

# 230514_ add underscore
caption_ = (righttext_[:6] + "_")
time.sleep(0.1)

keyboard.send_keys(caption_)
```